# Buying new remotes because of a LiftMaster failure?

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener

We have a LiftMaster model system installed in our parking garage, which seems not functional anymore. A service technician determined that the motor has failed. We received then two options: 1) either install a new same LiftMaster model (LiftMaster MYQ operator), or install a new Micanan model (Micanan commercial operator). The service company says that we will also need to buy new remotes. Does it make sense that we are asked to get new remotes (which is an expense of several thousands of dollars) because of an motor failure? What do you think about this situation? Thank you.

Comment: Please revise to tell us more about your hardware. If the failing unit is fairly new the remotes may be compatible. We can't say from what you've told us.

Comment: "a LiftMaster model"... what model? "system" what kind of system? These terms may be quite common in the UK, but they're unclear to this American. Also, asking "what do you think" invites opinions and that's strictly off-topic - [edit] your post to remove that and include more details including actual model numbers. It may be that someone can tell you how to replace the motor using _without_ having to replace the receiver unit, but without specifics, it would just be a guess.

Comment: While LiftMaster may not sell replacement motors, it's likely that the motor used is a standard motor that might be obtained from a industrial/commercial supply house.  Look at the motor and see if it has a manufacturer information plate or label and see if you can cross match it.

Comment: I added the models. I am just a resident - I can't access further details.

Comment: An update - they installed the Micanan commercial operator and were able to allow us use the same remotes that we have (no need to buy remotes). This involved configuring some receiver unit (which we had to buy but it was pretty cheap).

Answer (score 2):

Because they don't want to fix your unit. They want to sell you a whole new unit.  The unit they want to sell you has a different communication scheme with the remotes.

If you crunch the numbers, it makes perfect sense to do this: Sales commission on repair: $0.  Sales commission on new unit + 50 remotes: $lots. *I didn't say it made sense **for you.***

It's possible they lack the competence or ability to service the unit you do have, or they sent their salesman instead of their tech, whose goal was to sell you a new system before even pretending to look at it.  I would look for another company to service it.

The remote has nothing to do with the motor. The motor is the unit that pushes the door open and shut.  The remote connects to the control board, which tells the motor when to do that.   If the motor itself is fried, there is no earthly reason to need to change the remotes; motors can be repaired by a variety of shops.  *That makes me think the "tech" is not being honest*.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this makes sense is that the new motor unit has a receiver that operates on a different frequency than the original. If you can find a direct replacement for the failed motor unit, you may not have to replace all the remotes.

Comment: That assumes a generational change in the units. Many times remotes can be re-paired with similar units. We need more information to answer with confidence.

Comment: @isherwood Agreed, remotes have been pretty universal for at least 20 years. Even if the OP needs to replace the entire motorhead unit, they could be sure the new one is compatible with existing remotes.